# Want to create an app which can store my touch coordinates and add it to a notepad file on the smartphone

Tags: android

I would like to install the app on my tab where i would draw something on the screen and the app will store all X Y coordinates of my touch within a notepad file on the same device.
I am jst a begginer on programming but need this kind of app.
I downloaded android studio yesterday and I have little bit of knowledge on bluej.

Thanking in advance:)

Comment: The question is too broad. What have you tried? What fails?

Comment: I jst want to know how to start about some kind of guidance

Comment: Atleast the command line which can read the touch coordinates will be helpful. And if any package to be invoked or any object to be created please mention that also 

Comment: It is not clear if you want to build the drawing app yourself or you want to _intercept_ your drawing actions on on another app. In the first case, you should be able to see all drawing actions (and only those) when you process them. In the latter, you may run into difficulties 'spying' on another app, which Android/iOS tend to prevent. I guess you would have to pose as a kind of Accessibility app allowed to overlay other apps (special permissions).

Comment: No I want to make my own app(infact my first app)